# Ajax send large data MVC4

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm Trying to send large Data amount using ajax , it returns 404 error Not found , and if I send small amount of Data it respond with 200 and work Normally

here is my Code

```
var str = myDiagram.model.toJson();
    document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = str;
    myDiagram.isModified = false;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Workflow/PraseJson/?diagram=" + str
    }).done(function (x) {

    });
```

and Code for Controller

```
 public void PraseJson(string diagram)
    {
        object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(diagram);    
    }
```

I do not know how to solve this Issue, Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using POST to send data

> ```
>  $.ajax({
>         dataType: "json",
>         type: "POST",
>         data: {diagram: str },
>         url: "/Workflow/PraseJson/
>     }).done(function (x) { });
> ```

```
[HttpPost]
public void PraseJson(string diagram)
    {
        object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(diagram);    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mr/Awesome you are really awesome